# Display two metrics in one line in Grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana

[image]There are two metrics, one returns 100 as value and the second 200. I would like to display these two values in one line in grafana graph. On the left side of the line should be the minimum (100 in my example) and on the left side the maximum value (200). Is it possible to do so?

As a source for Grafana I'm using Prometheus.

Comment: I struggle to understand your idea. Could you add two screenshots: what you have now and how imagine it should be?

Comment: @markalex Sure, I added the screenshot. As you can see there are two lines showing two different values. I would like to display these values in one line

Comment: I don't think it's possible and it hard to imagine what should it mean. Closest thing I can suggest is switch to switch to Bar Chart and use two queries: `my_metric{label="label_value_for_bigger_one"}` and `my_metric{label="label_value_for_smaller_one"} @ start()`

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with field overrides:

1. Select the name of the field that you want to move on the right side;
2. Set Axis->Placement->Right

See below:
[image]